How to export a sql-datafile from postgreSQL via the terminal
I have completed a uni assignment creating a data mart via command line using PostgreSQL. Now I need to provide an export file for my hand-in.
I tried to use the following commands in the terminal:
pg_dump -U kirstincathlin -F p -d airbnb > airbnb.sql
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "pg_dump"
LINE 1: pg_dump -U kirstincathlin -F p -d airbnb > airbnb.sql
THEN
airbnb=# pg_dumpall > dump.sql;
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "pg_dumpall"

It appears that you are trying to run pg_dump from psql instead of the operating system's command line.

Could you explain the difference @JohnH
I understand that this is very basic, but it is my first attempt at sql and learning bash scripting so the infrastructure is still very abstract to me.
Thank you

I now tried it from the command line, the exact same prompt above and it says 'command not found'.
(base) kirstincathlin@re550-2 ~ % pg_dump -U kirstincathlin -F p -d airbnb > airbnb.sql
zsh: command not found: pg_dump
